# ReactJS: How to get state property of another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a main component, which uses a menu component. The menu component is using a state property to save the information about selected menu item. But now I need to get the selected module in the main component. How do I do that?

```
class Main extends Component {
    doSomething(module) {
        console.log(module) // should get 'targetValue'

        // I need to get the info, which module is selected.
        // This info is stored as a state value in the `MainMenu` Component
        // How do I get this information? I can't use the parameter `selectModule` as it is done here.
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MainMenu />
                <Button 
                    onClick={ this.doSomething.bind(this, selectedModule) }
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In this component a menu is generated for each module (of `modules` array). By clicking on one item, this module is stored into `module` state variable.

```
class MainMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            module: 'initialValue'
        }
    }

    selectModule(module) {
        this.setState({ module })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Menu>
                <Menu.Item onClick={ this.selectModule.bind(this, 'targetValue') } >
                    { title }
                </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of maintaining that state value in MainMenu component, maintain in Main component and pass that as a props to both component, and additionally pass a function to MainMenu to update that in Main component.

Comment: I don't understand how to get the state updated from the `MainMenu` component, which should then be at the `Main` component...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing some magic and examining internal state if children components lift the state to parent. Child becomes stateless.

```
class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    module: 'initialValue'
  }

  setActiveModule = (module) => {
    this.setState({ module })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MainMenu onChange={this.setActiveModule} />
    )
  }
}

class MainMenu extends Component {
  onClick = (module) => () => {
    this.props.onChange(module)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Menu>
        <Menu.Item onClick={this.onClick(title)} >
          {title}
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead on maintaining the `state` in MainMenu component, maintain in parent component Main, and pass the module value in `props`, also pass a `function` to MainMenu to update the `state` of parent component Main from child MainMenu.

Write it like this:

```
class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            module: 'initialValue'
        }
        this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    }

    update(value){
        this.setState({
            module: value
        });
    }

    doSomething(){
        console.log(this.state.module);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MainMenu module={this.state.module} update={this.update}/>
                <Button 
                    onClick={ this.doSomething.bind(this) }
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class MainMenu extends Component {

    selectModule(module) {
        this.props.update(module);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.module);
        return (
            <Menu>
                <Menu.Item onClick={this.selectModule.bind(this, 'targetValue') } >
                    { title }
                </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing state with react is sometimes a bit hard.

The react philosophy tends to say that we have to manage state from top to bottom. The idea is to modify the state in your parent, and pass the informations as props. For example, let's imagine the following scenario :

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  contructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentMenuSelected: 'Home' };
  }

  onPageChange(newPage) {
    this.setState({ currentMenuSelected: newPage });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <AnotherComponent currentMenu={this.state.currentMenuSelected} />
        <MenuWrapper onMenuPress={this.onPageChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In my example, we tell the `MenuWrapper` to use the `Main.onPageChange` when changing page. This way, we're now able to pass that current selected menu to `AnotherComponent` using props.

This is the first way to manage state sharing using react, and the default one provided by the *library*

If you want to manage more complex stuff, sharing more state, you should take a look at the flux architecture https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html

and the most common implementation of flux : http://redux.js.org/

Answer (score -1):

Store the menu state in the main component, and pass the state updater down to the menu.

This is quite helpful in getting into top-down state 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html